# Expanding a sequence inside a TikZ path

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

I am trying to draw a simple path using TikZ, with a custom syntax to specify it. This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\latticepath}[1]{
    \draw[thick] (0,0) node{} \foreach \x in {#1}{ -- \if u\x ++(0,1) \else ++(1,0) \fi node{}};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={circle,fill,draw=none,inner sep=2pt}}
    \latticepath{r,r,u,r,r,u,u,r,u,r,u,u}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would prefer not to comma-separate the values. So I wrote this command to convert a sequence of letters into path components:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter\let\mygobble\@gobble\makeatother
\newcommand{\readpath}[3]{
    \def\pathimpl##1{\ifx##1.\let\rest\mygobble\else\ifx##1u#1\else#2\fi\def\rest####1{####1}\fi\rest\pathimpl}
    \pathimpl#3.
}

\readpath{Up }{Right }{rrurruururuu}
```

[image]

However this implementation produces a bunch of errors due to the use of macros in paths:

```
\newcommand{\betterlatticepath}[1]{
    \draw[thick] (0,0) node{} \readpath{++(0,1) node{}}{++(1,0) node{}}{#1};
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{every node/.style={circle,fill,draw=none,inner sep=2pt}}
    \betterlatticepath{rrurruururuu}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.
>   Undefined control sequence.
>   You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
>   Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
>   Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
>   Argument of \rest has an extra }.
>   Runaway argument?

I tried `\pgfextra`, but this doesn't help. How can I make this work?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution using `\pgfextra`, `insert path` and two custom keys:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  recurse lattice path/.code args={#1#2}{
    \ifx#1.
    \else
    \ifx#1u
    \tikzset{insert path={-- ++(0,1) node[fill=black]{}}}
    \else
    \tikzset{insert path={-- ++(1,0) node[fill=black]{}}}
    \fi
    \tikzset{recurse lattice path=#2}
    \fi
  },
  lattice path/.code={%
    \draw (0,0) node[fill=black]{}
    \pgfextra{\tikzset{recurse lattice path={#1.}}};
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{lattice path=rrurrur}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Here is a simpler solution without `\pgfextra`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  dep u/.style={insert path={-- ++(0,1) node{}}},
  dep r/.style={insert path={-- ++(1,0) node{}}},
  dep d/.style={insert path={-- ++(0,-1) node{}}},
  dep l/.style={insert path={-- ++(-1,0) node{}}},
  recurse lattice path/.code args={#1#2}{
    \ifx#1.\else\tikzset{dep #1,recurse lattice path=#2}\fi
  },
  lattice path/.style={recurse lattice path=#1.}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{every node/.style={circle,fill,draw=none,inner sep=2pt}}
  \draw (0,0) node{} [lattice path=rrurrurrdddlll];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! But I don't quite understand how the `code args` part works. Why does `#1` get the first character while `#2` gets the entire remaining path?

Comment: @jtbandes That's basically how `TeX` works with delimited macros. Try `\tt \def\parse#1#2\eov{arg 1 -> (#1); arg 2 -> (#2);} \parse123456789\eov`. It is basically what is happening inside `\pgfkeys`.

Comment: @MarkWibrow That makes sense, I just didn't the `code args` setting is a delimited macro (since it just says `#1#2` and not `#1#2.`).

Answer (score 10):

Basically, you can't put a macro defined using `\newcommand` inside a TikZ path as it does a lot of stuff "under the covers" (e.g., `\futurelet`) which TikZ cannot handle.

You can, however, put arbitrary code inside `\pgfextra{}` in a TikZ path. In this case you could build the path inside `\pgfextra` and then insert it afterwards, like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\def\addtolatticepath#1{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\latticepath\expandafter{\latticepath#1}%
}

\def\latticepathletteru{\addtolatticepath{ -- ++(0,1) }}
\def\latticepathletterd{\addtolatticepath{ -- ++(0,-1) }}
\def\latticepathletterl{\addtolatticepath{ -- ++(-1,0) }}
\def\latticepathletterr{\addtolatticepath{ -- ++(1,0) }}

\def\parselatticepath#1{%
  \def\latticepath{node {}}%
  \Parselatticepath#1@}
\def\Parselatticepath#1{%
  \ifx#1@%
    \let\next=\relax%
  \else%
    \csname latticepathletter#1\endcsname%
    \addtolatticepath{ node {} }%
    \let\next=\Parselatticepath
  \fi%
  \next}

\tikzset{%
  insert lattice path/.style={%
    every node/.style={
      circle,
      fill,
      draw=none,
      inner sep=2pt
    },
    insert path={%
      \pgfextra{\parselatticepath{#1}}%
      \latticepath
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [insert lattice path={rrurruururuu}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but as I do not see a lot of answers here using `parser` PGF library, I add one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{parser}

% macro that add #1 to the current path when used inside \pgfextra 
\def\insertpath#1{\tikzset{insert path={#1}}}
% define the parser "lattice path" 
\pgfparserdef{lattice path}{initial}{the letter u}{\insertpath{node{} -- ++(0,1) }}
\pgfparserdef{lattice path}{initial}{the letter r}{\insertpath{node{} -- ++(1,0) }}
\pgfparserdef{lattice path}{initial}{the letter d}{\insertpath{node{} -- ++(0,-1)}}
\pgfparserdef{lattice path}{initial}{the letter l}{\insertpath{node{} -- ++(-1,0)}}
\pgfparserdef{lattice path}{initial}{the character .}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,fill=red,inner sep=2pt}]
    \draw (0,0) \pgfextra{\pgfparserparse{lattice path}rrurrurrdddlll.} node{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]